# Safari 15 Desktop. How to set input field 'date' to empty default value

Tags: forms, safari, datefield

I'm currently working on a html form with input type="date" fields.
Unfortunately Safari 15 sets current date as a default value in every empty date field.
Is there a way to set the default to empty? Like in Chrome dd-mm-yyyy.
Thank you! :)